# What is wrong in my script, tell me please

Tags: linux, perl

I need that scipt enter in my router on page and find the code and compared with earlier this IP information recorded, and if not changed, then stop the script.

I run this script - $ perl ~/test.pl

no error, but file my_ip.txt is not created.

In originals script must check my ip through host example.dyndns.org, but my ip is gray.

So I need to be determined through a router

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    use LWP::UserAgent;

my $routeraddress = `addr admin:Tavolzhansky@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm`;
if ($routeraddress =~ /var info_get_wanip="((\d+\.){3}(\d+))"/) {

  my $ip = "$1.$2.$3.$4";

   #Добавлено:
  open (FILE,"my_ip.txt");
  my @lines = <FILE>;
  $old_ip = $lines[0]; #Считываем IP из файла
  $old_ip =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; #trim
  close(FILE);
  if ($old_ip eq $ip) {
    die "IP not changed"; # Выходим из скрипта, если IP не изменился
  }
  open (FILE,">my_ip.txt");
  print FILE $ip; # Записываем в файл новый IP
  close(FILE);
...... (this code is OK)
}
```

Do not bring the end of the code because the problem by connecting to the router

Comment: Turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;` and `use autodie;` - the latter will generate an error if your `open` fails. At a guess, permissions denied.

Comment: use strict; did not help. Errors as the original with old_ip, but it works in the original

Comment: what does the `addr` command return?

Comment: please don't tag a Q that is all `perl` code with `bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ perl -cw -e 'print `addr admin:foo@192.168.1.1/bar`'
Possible unintended interpolation of @192 in string at -e line 1.
-e syntax OK
```

It doesn't work because `@192` is interpolated as an array, and you are running the command `addr admin:Tavolzhansky.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm` instead of the command you meant to.

This would have been very easy to spot and fix if you would `use warnings`, if you would step through the code with the debugger, or as Andy suggests, if you would examine return values.

---

To get `@192` to not be interpolated, escape the `@`:

```
my $routeraddress = `addr admin:Tavolzhansky\@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm`;
```

Comment: Fun fact: `@192` is a valid array identifier in Perl, and like `@ARGV`, `%SIG`, or `%ENV`, is always interpreted to be in the `main` package. It cannot be given a lexical scope with `my`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because of this:

```
my $routeraddress = `addr admin:Tavolzhansky@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm`;
if ($routeraddress =~ /var info_get_wanip="((\d+\.){3}(\d+))"/) {
    ...
}
```

Try adding a couple debug prints to confirm like:

```
my $routeraddress = `addr admin:Tavolzhansky@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm`;
print "Router IP = $routeraddress/n";

if ($routeraddress =~ /var info_get_wanip="((\d+\.){3}(\d+))"/) {
    ...
} else {
    print "Router address didn't match.\n";
}
```

You should use the strict and warning pragmas, but as you said this worked when you were getting your IP from a different source, the rest of the code will work.

I'm guessing you're reading an HTML page and expecting to see this string somewhere:

```
var info_get_wanip="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
```

However, you need to confirm if $routeraddress is actually getting that, it looks like

```
my $routeraddress = `addr admin:Tavolzhansky@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm`;
```

Is just essentially making a get request for the page, but isn't returning "var info_get_wanip="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";". If you sort the assignment of the variable $routeraddress, then it'll work.

I can't say how, as I don't know what it's returning now.